# does dexed file persistent in the system ? Does it exist after rebooting the device ? if yes where stored?

Tags: android, dalvik, dex, android-framework

Question:

**Does Dex Optimization happens each time we reboot the device ?  Or the dex files are stored into the system itself, and used for second time ?**

Directory  :  **system/framework**

Files      :  **core.jar, core-junit.jar , framework.jar , etc...**

**Source Code Analysis:**

It looks like,  the system check if there is already dex file in the cache, if exist, it just ignores, if not it creates a dex file.

http://androidxref.com/4.1.2/xref/dalvik/vm/RawDexFile.cpp :

```
  optFd = dvmOpenCachedDexFile(fileName, cachedName, modTime,
        adler32, isBootstrap, &newFile, /*createIfMissing=*/true);


   This 'newFile'  flag tells if dex file exists in the cache,
```

Below is the code which actually invokes dex optimization over the file.

```
if (newFile) {
   ......

  result = dvmOptimizeDexFile(optFd, dexOffset, fileSize,
            fileName, modTime, adler32, isBootstrap);
```

*Logcat Output:*

```
03-29 12:16:59.617 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DexOpt: --- END 'core.jar' (success) ---

03-29 12:16:59.617 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DEX prep '/system/framework/core.jar': unzip in 239ms, rewrite 3943ms

03-29 12:16:59.617 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'core-junit.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---

03-29 12:16:59.664 D/dalvikvm( 1372): DexOpt: load 4ms, verify+opt 10ms, 137044 bytes

03-29 12:17:00.250 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DexOpt: --- END 'core-junit.jar' (success) ---

03-29 12:17:00.250 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DEX prep '/system/framework/core-junit.jar': unzip in 
0ms, rewrite 627ms

03-29 12:17:00.304 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'bouncycastle.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---

03-29 12:17:00.882 D/dalvikvm( 1373): DexOpt: load 25ms, verify+opt 463ms, 598508 bytes

03-29 12:17:01.507 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DexOpt: --- END 'bouncycastle.jar' (success) ---

03-29 12:17:01.507 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DEX prep '/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar': unzip 
in 49ms, rewrite 1204ms

03-29 12:17:01.632 D/dalvikvm( 1071): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ext.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of dexopt is stored in `/data/dalvik-cache`.

On production devices, apps and bootstrap classes on the system partition have ".odex" files stored next to the .dex files.  If a built-in app is updated, the APK will be stored on the data partition, and the odex will go into dalvik-cache as usual.

dexopt is usually run by the package manager.  The app process doesn't have permission to create files in `/data/dalvik-cache`, so the package manager has to create the file and run dexopt before the app starts.  The only exception to this is for the bootstrap classes, where dexopt is run by zygote, and that only happens on development builds.

The [dexopt documentation](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/dexopt.html) is a bit out of date but is mostly accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. IF i understand correctly your points, 1) .odex are persistent. that is each time no need to create unless a new application is installed. [ probably the very first time the .odex are generated and kept in the dalvik-cache ? 2) For engineering build, zygote takes care of dexopt for boot classes. 3) pre-loading classes into VM ofcourse takes in place on every time device is booted. Kindly help to understand it.

Comment: There are other details, e.g. after a system update that changes the bootstrap classes, all app .odex must be regenerated, but I think you've got the right idea.